# Verb from "scoping review"

Tags: adverbs

Instead of writing

> We performed a **systematic review** of articles

some academic authors write

> We **systematically reviewed** articles

to saves 3 words -- for the purpose of word count limit.

Now, what is the verb from *scoping review*?

I found this very bizarre:

> We **[scopingly] reviewed** articles

Comment: *Scopingly*?  Really?

Comment: Clearly not. The question is what one could write instead.

Comment: Whew!  I understood from the question post that you saw that somewhere!

Comment: Would this work?  *We scoped a number of review articles [for such-and-so content or characteristics*.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear :)  --- No, this doesn't convey the same meaning of "we performed a scoping review of 50 articles".

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment.  Also, I just realized I was guessing as to the meaning of *scoping review* but now I'm not sure.  Could you edit the question and explain the term, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what "scope" means in this context, but perhaps "examined" says what you want. To examine something is to look at it closely.

Comment: A [scoping review](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/56237.pdf?repositoryId=140) is a study that aims to *map rapidly* the key concepts in a research area -- rapid mapping rather than in a strict and systematic way (as in a systematic review).